# Unable to start a React template (Volt) because of a missing script "start"

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am unable to run a React template called [Volt](https://demo.themesberg.com/volt-react-dashboard/#/documentation/quick-start) on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Using:

- Node - v17.1.0
- NPM - 8.1.2

As per the docs, in the main volt folder, I run `npm install` to install all the dependencies, without any issues.

I then try `npm start` which returns `npm ERR! Missing script: "start"`.

`package.json` does not contain any scripts. I tried adding the following, but I don't know which file I should provide for the start script:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "?"
}
```

The main volt directory contains only 1 .js file named `gulpfile.js`. I tried:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "gulpfile.js"
}
```

which returns `sh: 1: gulpfile.js: not found`

This is the overview of the directory [image: Directory overview]

My question is:
What steps should I take to launch the Volt template on a localhost, given the current errors?

Comment: Where did you get that Volt template? The link you provided downloads a totally different template (which includes a start script). Your template doesn't even look like it has React included (perhaps bootstrap?)

Since there's gulp here, I'd suggest you just put `gulp` in your start script. However it's totally dependent on what the gulpfile looks like.